# point root to sub-directory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have the rule to redirect all request to https and point to `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !{"scheme":"https"}
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

the root directory is `htdocs`, but i need change it to point to `htdocs/public` because some framework implement public folder has root. the problem is that i fin that example:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/$ /yourfile.php [L]
```

It's not clear to me how to implement it.

**update:**

my `.htaccess` file is in the root directory: `htdocs`, then `index.php` is located in `htdocs/public`, in this subdirectory I don't have the `.htaccess`

finally what I am looking for is that when entering a url like:

```
https://your-example.com/
https://www.your-example.com/
https://www.your-example.com/test-foo/
https://www.your-example.com/test-foo?data=data&foo=foo
```

all these requests point to `index.php` in the subdirectory:

`htdocs/public/index.php`

***update 2:***

my current routing in `/public/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "and point to `index.php`" - where is that? Do you have another `.htaccess` file at `/public/.htaccess`?

Comment: @MrWhite i have update the context, thank for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

> the root directory is htdocs, but i need change it to point to htdocs/public because some framework implement public folder has root.

Ordinarily, if you have access to the server config then you would "simply" change the `DocumentRoot` in the server config to point to the `/public` subdirectory. Alternatively, if you have access to the directory above the document root (as you appear to) then move the file structure "up" a level, so that the files in the `/public` subdirectory are moved to the document root (ie. `htdocs/`) and the framework/system files are in a directory above the document root, outside of the public HTML space (as they should be).

However, if you don't have access to the server config and/or are unable to move the files, and you have a `/public` subdirectory off the document root then proceed as follows...

I assume your current HTTP to HTTPS rule/redirect is working OK for you (since this is specific to Cloudflare)? However, the rule you posted does not route anything to `index.php` as you appear to suggest and the `Protocols` directive is not permitted in `.htaccess` (and should be triggering an error) - so not sure what that is doing there?

You need to add a rewrite to the root `.htaccess` file (ie. `/htdocs/.htaccess`) that rewrites all requests to the `/public` subdirectory. And create an additional `.htaccess` at `/htdocs/public/.htaccess` that routes all requests to `public/index.php` (your *front-controller*).

For example, try it like this:

```
# htdocs/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !{"scheme":"https"}
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite all requests to the "/public" subdirectory
# You could do this unconditionally, depending on your requirements.
# ie. You don't necessarily need to check for existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Also consider canonicalising the www vs non-www hostname (ie. redirect one to the other). This would go in the root `.htaccess` file before or after the HTTP to HTTPS redirect (depending on requirements, ie. are you implementing HSTS?).

Create a second `.htaccess` file at `htdocs/public/.htaccess` with the following:

```
# htdocs/public/.htaccess

DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Route all requests to "index.php" (front-controller)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I quick analysis of your existing rules, but as I mentioned in comments, the version I described above is preferable.

> my current routing in `/public/.htaccess`:
>
> ```
> DirectoryIndex index.php
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine on
>     RewriteBase /
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

The `RewriteBase /` directive here is incorrect and will break the rules when located in the `/public` subdirectory. This would need to be either set to `RewriteBase /public` or removed altogether (preferable).

The `QSA` flag is not required since you are not including a query string in the *substitution*.

`^(.*)$` - the capturing group is less efficient and not required (you are not making use of any backreferences here).

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required and should be removed. This would only be required if these directives are optional (they are not) and you are moving these directives to multiple servers where mod_rewrite might not be enabled.

The filesystem checks to make sure the request does not map to a directory (`!-d`) and is not a symbolic link (`!-l`) are generally not required (and consequently is an unnecessary overhead if they are not reqd). These should be removed, unless you specifically need to access filesystem directories (or symbolic links) directly (which is rare).

Comment: I'm sorry, you were right; I have been left to add the routing rule that is in the htaccess inside public; you can take a look at it.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Use the `public/.htaccess` version as posted in my answer. The `RewriteBase /` directive in your code would break the rules when located in the `/public` subdirectory. Do you need to be able to access physical directories and symbolic links within `/public`? (This is rare.) Otherwise, those additional conditions are superfluous.

Comment: yes, becouse in public i have the Js, jpe, css files ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 - those are "files", not "directories" (or "symbolic links"). _Aside:_ How are you referencing your static resources in your HTML? Generally, you should _not_ be referencing `/public` in the URL anywhere (although these directives will work either way). I've updated my answer to add some analysis of your "current rules".